# Auto Categorization Of Android Application

Tags: android, categorization

How do I automatically categorise an android application ? I need to write a code to do it.
There exists an api & android application CatApplus http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1419810.
But it is not freely available.
Can anyone suggest any alternative or any other way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this api to get apps category then you categorize them the way you like.

[Android-market-api](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)

Comment: This api connects to google's official android market servers for information and Search for apps using keywords or package name. What if the app is not downloaded from Google play? It cannot be categorised then?

Comment: if it's dl'ed it can't =(